# Cursor is not visible onclicking Action Done keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

I am working on Dynamic Edit Text and here by am facing an issue that cursor is not visible in edit text field after clicking **Action DONE** in soft keyboard.

In this code i am doing cursor visibility false after clicking **Action Done** in keyboard and if go back to first edit text field and came to the final edit text field the cursor is not showing.Suggest me some idea how to bring the cursor point to the edit text field after clicking **Action Done** in keyboard?

```
  eView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                            //Clear focus here from edittext
                            eView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                            eView.setCursorVisible(false);

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `clearFocus()` on `actionDone` it will clear the focus from current view no need for `setCursorVisible(false)`.

```
eView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                eView.clearFocus();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if i gave clearfocus()  it was going to some other field with cursor blinking on it..

Comment: Yeah thats what the default behavior is. What's your need ?

Comment: Thanks for your concern @ADM I just want to enable the cursor only on tapping the field

Comment: You can set the initial focus on some other view. Use attribute `nextFocusDown` for next focus .